# Display the foreign key in multiple tables in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm currently working on a simple search website. I'm using php and mysql workbench. My problem is in my article page below I can't display the actual name of the location and vendor, these are in a different table but is connected via foreign key in my "copy" table. It only shows the acronym and the number that corresponds to the actual word. Sorry for my bad english. I will insert a picture of my er diagram.

**ER Diagram Here:**

[image: ER Diagram Here]

**Search Page :**

```
<?php
    include 'header.php';
?>

<div id= "Title">
    <h1>Online Public Access Catalog</h1>
</div>

<div id="navbar">
    <h2> DISCOVERY SERVICE</h2>
    <form id="SearchBar" action="search.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="search" class="search" placeholder="Search Here">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class= "submit">Submit</button> 
</form>
<h3 class="enterword"> Enter a word or phrase and press submit</h3>

</body>
</html>
```

**Search Result Page :**

```
<?php
    include 'header.php'
?>

<h1 class="searchresults">Search Results:</h1>

<div class="search-container">
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['search']);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE Book_Title LIKE '%$search%' OR Author LIKE '%$search%' OR Call_Number LIKE '%$search%'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        echo "<h3 class='resultcount'>There are ".$queryResult." results!</h3>";

        if ($queryResult > 0)
        {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                echo "<a href='article.php?Book_Title=".$row['Book_Title']."&id=".$row['Book_ID']."' class= 'search-ref'><div class=search-box>
                <tr><td>".$row['Book_Title']." </td>
                <td>/ ".$row['Author']."</td>
                <p>".$row['Call_Number']."</p>
                </div></tr><br>";
            }

        }
    }
    ?>
    <input type="button" value="Back" onclick="history.back(-1)" />
</div>

<!-- Article Page -->
<?php
    include 'header.php';
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="article-container">


<?php
//Declairing Variables
$Author = "Authors: ";
$Edition = "Edition: ";
$Subject ="Subject: ";
$Summary = "Summary: ";
$Notes = "Notes: ";
$Publisher ="Publisher: ";
$Phys_Desc ="Physical Description: ";
$Call_Number ="Call Number: ";
$Book_ID = "Book ID: ";


$Title= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['Book_Title']);

$sql ="SELECT * FROM book WHERE Book_Title='$Title'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);      
$queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($queryResult > 0)
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo "<div class= 'article-box'>
    <h3 class='booktitle'><b>".$row['Book_Title']."</h3></b>
    <p><b>$Author</b>".$row['Author']."</p>
    <p><b>$Edition</b>".$row['Edition']."</p>
    <p><b>$Subject</b>".$row['Subject']."</p>
    <p><b>$Summary</b>".$row['Summary']."</p>
    <p><b>$Notes</b>".$row['Notes']."</p>
    <p><b>$Publisher</b>".$row['Publisher']."</p>
    <p><b>$Phys_Desc</b>".$row['Phys_Desc']."</p>
    <p><b>$Call_Number</b>".$row['Call_Number']."</p>
</div>";
}
?>
<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="history.back(-1)" />
<!-- POP-UP WINDOW -->
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Copies</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Copies</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <table class = "table">
    <tr>
        <th>Barcode</th>
        <th>Copy</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Format</th>
        <th>Vendor</th>
    </tr>
          <?php
  {
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM copy WHERE Book_ID='$id'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($queryResult > 0)
    {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
      {

        echo "
        <tr><td>".$row['Barcode']."</td>
        <td>".$row['Copy']."</td>
        <td>".$row['Status']."</td>
        <td>".$row['Location']."</td>
        <td>".$row['Format']."</td>
        <td>".$row['Vendor']."</td></tr>
        ";
      }

    }

  }
  ?>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the problem is. Have you tried joining the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use JOIN in your query.

```
SELECT Barcode, Copy, Status, l.Location, f.Format, Vendor
FROM copy c
INNER JOIN location l ON l.Location_Acronym = c.Location
INNER JOIN format f ON f.Format_ID = c.Format
WHERE Book_ID='$id'
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  This solved my problem. It worked. :)